# Java : Getting the next child node with SAXParser

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I have the following XML structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <person name="foobar">
        <age>45</age>
        <city>SOTown</city>
    </person>
    <person name="tester">
        <age>51</age>
        <city>There</city>
    </person>
</root>
```

I'm using SAXParser and I can get the node elements like this (it's simplified) :

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
if (name.equals("person")){
Person p = new Person();
p.name = attributes.getValue("name");
p.age = ???
p.city = ???
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {

}
```

The problem is at the `p.age` and `p.city` lines.

How can I get that child nodes values ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can change the content handler during processing, which allows you to maintain state and do contextual processing. For example, consider this self-contained example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;    
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private XMLReader reader;
    private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
            SAXHandler tester = new SAXHandler(saxParser.getXMLReader());
            saxParser.parse("workbook.xml", tester);
            System.out.println(tester.people);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public SAXHandler(XMLReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }

    public Person addPerson(Person person) {
        this.people.add(person);
        return person;
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if ("person".equals(qName)) {
            String name = attributes.getValue("name");
            this.reader.setContentHandler(new PersonHandler(this.reader, this,
                    name));
        }
        System.out.println("Start Element: " + qName);
    }
}
```

Notice that we `setContentHandler` whenever we encounter a `person` element. The `PersonHandler` looks like this:

```
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class PersonHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private Person currPerson;
    private StringBuilder content;
    private XMLReader reader;
    private SAXHandler parentHandler;

    public PersonHandler(XMLReader reader, SAXHandler parentHandler, String name) {
        this.reader = reader;
        this.parentHandler = parentHandler;
        this.currPerson = new Person(name);
        this.content = new StringBuilder();
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        this.content.setLength(0);
        System.out.println("PersonHandler::Start Element: " + qName);
    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if ("age".equals(qName)) {
            this.currPerson.setAge(this.content.toString());
        } else if ("city".equals(qName)) {
            this.currPerson.setCity(this.content.toString());
        } else if ("person".equals(qName)) {
            this.parentHandler.addPerson(this.currPerson);
            this.reader.setContentHandler(this.parentHandler);
        }
        System.out.println("PersonHandler::End Element: " + qName);
    }

    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        this.content.append(ch, start, length);
    }

}
```

Notice that we reset the content handler to the parent handler whenever we are done processing the `person`.

For completeness, here's a (very) minimal `Person`:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String age;
    private String city;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(String string) {
        this.age = string;
    }

    public void setCity(String string) {
        this.city = string;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name + " " + this.age + " " + this.city;
    }
}
```

This code would output:

```
Start Element: root
Start Element: person
PersonHandler::Start Element: age
PersonHandler::End Element: age
PersonHandler::Start Element: city
PersonHandler::End Element: city
PersonHandler::End Element: person
Start Element: person
PersonHandler::Start Element: age
PersonHandler::End Element: age
PersonHandler::Start Element: city
PersonHandler::End Element: city
PersonHandler::End Element: person
```

Comment: So does this mean we can chain handlers for different nodes (e.g.: company > department > worker > address)?

Comment: Sorry mate, but I don't think this works the way you want it to. Look: the Start Element is called by the time you are looking at the child. There is no way to get attributes of the parent, and yet in the PersonHandler class there we have you trying to get the attribute "name" for the person name. Well it is too late to do that, we'd have to get it from SAXHandler. Or is there another way to do that?

Comment: FYI, I will be attempting to resolve this by passing in the localname, qname and attributes into the PersonHandler and creating the Person object in the constructor. I think this will work better, especially for schemas where a node can contain another instance of its own class (ie, a Person that can contain a person)

Comment: Good catch @IcedDante. You're totally right, as is your suggested solution. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't directly, you would have to set a boolean instance variable to
indicate you are now inside a `person` element and set the persons attributes
inside the `endElement` method. The character content gets passed to the
`characters` method and has to be appended to a buffer since the parser is
allowed to call this method multiple times.

```
StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
boolean inPerson = false;
Person person;

// characters can be called multiple times per element, so aggregate the content in a StringBuilder
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    content.append(ch, start, length);
}

public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    // reset the character buffer
    content.setLength(0);
    if (localName.equals("person")) {
        this.person = new Person();
        this.person.name = attributes.getValue("name");
        this.inPerson = true;
    } 
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (inPerson) {
        if (localName.equals("age")) {
            this.person.age = Integer.parseInt(content.toString());
        } else if (localName.equals("city")) {
            this.person.city = content.toString();
        } else if (localName.equals("person")) {
            this.inPerson = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code : Replace start and End Elements and Declare Person class object in top...

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
String content;
Person p;

public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
{
    if (localName.equals("person")) {
        p = new Person();
        p.name = attributes.getValue("name");
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName,
        String qName) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equals("age"))  {
        p.age = = Integer.parseInt(content.toString());
    } 

    if (localName.equals("city")) {          
        p.city  = content;
    } 

    if (localName.equals("person")) {
        persons.add(p);
    }
}

public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
    content= new String(ch, start, length); 
}
```

Any doubt or suggestion ?, You are welcomed...